# Aggregate hash function?

Tags: sql, teradata

Just like we have aggregate functions of sum and count, is there any way to do aggregate hashes on field?  For example, assume you have the following recordset:

```
Name     ID
Bob      1
Bob      2
Bob      3
Bob      4
```

*Conceptually*, I'd like to do this:

```
select name, hash(id) from mydb.mytable
group by 1
```

...which would return this:

```
Name     ID
Bob      D8-F0-00-91
```

If I delete the record with ID = 3, the aggregate would then return this:

```
Name     ID
Bob      A8-EB-6D-1D
```

FYI, I used `select hashrow(1,2,3,4)` and `select hashrow(1,2,4)` to get the above hash values.

**Update for dnoeth:**  It's probably helpful to mention that I need the resulting aggregate to be unique.  Here's an example of the data model I am using:

```
table office (Id integer)
table employee (Id integer, OfficeId integer)
```

Each office has employees, so it's a one-to-many from office to employee with the employee table having OfficeId as a FK to the office table.

```
locking row for access
select n, count(n) from
(
    select 
        officeid, 
        sum(cast(from_bytes('00'xb || hashrow(id), 'base10') as bigint)) n 
    from mydb.employee
    group by 1
) x
group by 1
```

Here's a great example of how a collision occurs.  Again, though, I didn't mention that I needed the result to be unique.

```
select 
    cast(from_bytes('00'xb || hashrow(2300015), 'base10') as bigint) +
    cast(from_bytes('00'xb || hashrow(14100028), 'base10') as bigint) hash1,

    cast(from_bytes('00'xb || hashrow(1000004), 'base10') as bigint) +
    cast(from_bytes('00'xb || hashrow(3100014), 'base10') as bigint) +
    cast(from_bytes('00'xb || hashrow(12300025), 'base10') as bigint) hash2
```

Comment: There are hash related functions. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @RobPaller I updated my answer for better clarity.

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast the result of the HASHROW to a numeric value, then you can easily sum it.

```
-- HASHROW to unsigned integer, TD14
SUM(CAST(FROM_BYTES('00'xb||HASHROW(ColumnName), 'base10') AS BIGINT)
   ) AS SumHash

-- HASHROW to unsigned integer, pre-TD14
SUM(  HASHBUCKET(       HASHROW(ColumnName)      (BYTE(4)))  / ((HASHBUCKET()+1)/65536) * CAST(65536 AS BIGINT)
    + HASHBUCKET(SUBSTR(HASHROW(ColumnName),3,2) (BYTE(4)))  / ((HASHBUCKET()+1)/65536)
   ) AS SumHash
```

**Edit:**

There's no way to get a guaranteed unique result when hashing, there's just a increasing probability based on the length of the calculated hash. And HASHROW returns a 4 byte value and you simply add them :-(

You could install an existing hashing UDF returning way more than 4 bytes like

https://downloads.teradata.com/download/extensibility/sha-1-message-digest-udf

https://downloads.teradata.com/download/extensibility/md5-message-digest-udf

https://github.com/akuroda/teradata-udf-sha2

and then implement an Aggregate **XOR** UDF.

There was a blog on Teradata's DevEx about comparing tables:

http://developer.teradata.com/blog/ulrich/2013/05/calculation-of-table-hash-values-to-compare-table-content

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that I need the aggregated result to be unique (which is why an aggregate hash would be great).  When I 1) execute your SUM method on an UPI field in a table with 10k rows, 2) group by parent foreign key, and then 3) do a COUNT on the SUMmed results, I get some collisions.  I suppose it's the same type of collision you'd get when adding 10, 30, 50, 70 to get 160 and then take completely different numbers of 5, 35, 40, 80 and also get 160.  I updated my answer with some example SQL.

Comment: Hmmm... I wonder if a "cumulative" hash would work.  Basically, generate a hash and then hash that hash with the hash of the previous row.  Or perhaps there's a way to create an aggregate INTEGER array and then pass that array through `hashrow()`.  I am just thinking, really.

Comment: In response to your edit, I am aware that hashes aren't guaranteed to be unique, but I think summing random groups of hashes greatly increases the probability of a collision.  I just used hashrow() on a UPI in a table with 11k records and every one was unique, but summing groups of those hashes generated a noteworthy amount of collisions (see my previous 10,30,50,70 example).  At any rate, I think we can conclude that the answer is No, there is no aggregate hash function and that some other method will need to be used such as the UDFs as you proposed.